# How can I disable FileVault Encryption Process? (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, security, encryption, filevault, system-preferences

I enabled FileVault on my Mac (MacOS High Sierra) in the Security and Privacy System Preferences. Now my computer is extremely slow, I can't even use it.

FileVault is still in the process of encrypting my files (and will be for a very long time) and I would like to just hault the process and disable FileVault ASAP. I have tried the sudo fdesetup disable command in the Terminal many times and it just gives me the message:

FileVault was not disabled (-69573).

I am open to any suggestions on how to stop the FileVault encryption process and keep FileVault off. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Have you tried via the GUI first, in Preferences under Security? Alternatively, you can try to Start up in Recovery mode. When the macOS Utilities screen appears, select Disk Utility. There, select the icon of the startup *volume* from the list on the left. Click the Unlock button in the toolbar. Enter your admin password, or the alternate decryption key that was generated when you activated FileVault if you kept it. Then, from the menu bar, select File ▹ Turn Off Encryption, enter the password again. You should be able to restart quickly, since you're in Recovery Mode.

Comment: You already asked this on Ask Different and got an answer - [How can FileVault encryption process be stopped/disabled?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388994/how-can-filevault-encryption-process-be-stopped-disabled). Best not to cross-post.

Comment: @didier Unfortunately the High Sierra OS doesn't allow you to turn off encryption this simply :( But thank you for the suggestion. I'm going to try the steps from this link and see if I can get them to work: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/unlock-or-decrypt-an-encrypted-apfs-boot-drive-from-the-command-line/

Comment: In case anyone reads my previous comment, I followed all of the steps in the article but they are made to start a decryption process after the encryption process is complete, not to stop current encryption process and just decrypt what's already been encrypted

Comment: Yes, I can see that. It's one of the few examples of Apple lacking where Windows shines, I suppose: BitLocker is the (rough) equivalent of FileVault, but it works more transparently for the end-user, and decryption takes a lot less time than FileVault. Different protocols can explain that, but Apple's new files system's flexibility leaves to be desired, sometimes. Hang in there!